# Change custom 404 error page

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404

Some time ago I changed my 404 error page to the main page of my site.  (Silly of me, but I'm new at this and it seemed like a good idea at the time.)

Trouble is, I forget how I accomplished it. I was trying the TextPattern CMS at one time, and I think I did it in the CMS, but I don't remember how.

Nowadays, I'm not using the CMS (but the database is still there), and I've created a more descriptive error page, and I've updated my .htaccess file, but the behaviour doesn't  change--still the old error (bad) page comes back.  I've tried the following in my .htaccess file, all to no avail

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 404 http:/www.mysite.com/404.shtml
ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Google Webmaster Tools reports 54 "soft 404" errors, which I gotta fix!

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I expect that such soft 404 pages are error pages with the server response code 200 and not 404.

It depends a little on the software you are using on the server. I think that your script 404.shtml returns the wrong response code so far you need to edit that file that it will return the response code 404.

In PHP you can do that with:

```
header("Not Found", 404, true);
```

Please note that this line must stand before any output!